# "Canon" for technical subjects

Tags: word-choice, metaphors

Can you say

> Despite initial success, method A has not found its way into the canon
>   of cancer treatments.

What I mean by "canon" is simply that method A is not one of those that a normal doctor at a normal hospital would suggest or would have learned about during his studies.

Looking at [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canon) definition, I think that the 4.th meaning might cover my usage, but I am not sure because the focus there is on 'principles', not 'methods'. Similarly, [most other definitions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/canon) [that I looked at](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/canon) are even more limited to religious, poetic, or musical meaning.

Comment: Remember that dictionary definitions often lag actual usage by an unknown amount of time. Your usage of _canon_ here would go unremarked by all but perhaps the most pedantic grammarians.

Comment: Go with what's appropriate for the discipline.  The usual term in medicine is "standard of care".

Answer (score 12):

It is not incorrect, but it would be more common to see the adjective **canonical** than the phrase **find its way into the canon**, which is a phrase normally reserved for texts. The adjective **canonical** is figurative, based on that meaning.

> The canonical treatment paradigm for virtually all cancers, including prostate cancer, has been to target the tumor cell directly.

OR

> Furthermore, VEGFR2 knockdown BCPAP (shVEGFR2) cells showed a significant decrease in thyroid cancer patients who fail to respond to the canonical treatment...

Thus, something like

> Despite showing early promise, X has not become a canonical treatment for Y.

Answer (score 11):

The definition of the word "*canon*" appropriate here is:

> the writings or other works that are generally agreed to be good, important, and worth studying.

I understand "*the canon of cancer treatments*" to be the "catalogue", or collection of treatments which the medical profession agree are effective or worthwhile.

The term is not used to describe a *complete* collection of anything, but rather the *accepted* collections, excluding things that are considered of having no value, or little worth, or are *apocryphal*. Items not included in the accepted collection are termed *non-canonical*.